Include a custom ribbon button for a excel file
I need a ribbon tab / button to come up only when a particular file is open in excel.  And when clicked it runs the macro contained in that excel file.
Like I want to include the ribbon tab / button as part of the file, so that when I send the file via email, and when the other person opens the file, he gets to see a custom button in their menu bar.
Is this doable? Can someone share any idea.

Definitely doable. What have you tried and where are you stuck?
